# Points on sphere

Tags: python, numpy, geometry

I am new in Python and I have a sphere of radius (R) and centred at (x0,y0,z0). Now, I need to find those points which are either on the surface of the sphere or inside the sphere e.g. points (x1,y1,z1) which satisfy ((x1-x0)**2+(y1-y0)**2+(z1-x0)*82)**1/2 <= R. I would like to print only those point's coordinates in a form of numpy array. Output would be something like this-[[x11,y11,z11],[x12,y12,z12],...]. I have the following code so far-

```
import numpy as np
import math

def create_points_around_atom(number,atom_coordinates):
    n= number
    x0 = atom_coordinates[0]
    y0 = atom_coordinates[1]
    z0 = atom_coordinates[2]
    R = 1.2
    for i in range(n):
        phi = np.random.uniform(0,2*np.pi,size=(n,))
        costheta = np.random.uniform(-1,1,size=(n,))
        u = np.random.uniform(0,1,size=(n,))
        theta = np.arccos(costheta)
        r = R * np.cbrt(u)
        x1 = r*np.sin(theta)*np.cos(phi) 
        y1 = r*np.sin(theta)*np.sin(phi)
        z1 = r*np.cos(theta)
        dist  = np.sqrt((x1-x0)**2+(y1-y0)**2+(z1-z0)**2)
        distance = list(dist)
        point_on_inside_sphere = []
        for j in distance:
            if j <= R:
                point_on_inside_sphere.append(j)
                print('j:',j,'\tR:',R)
                print('The list is:', point_on_inside_sphere)
                print(len(point_on_inside_sphere))
                kk =0
                for kk in range(len(point_on_inside_sphere)):
                    for jj in point_on_inside_sphere:
                        xx = np.sqrt(jj**2-y1**2-z1**2)
                        yy = np.sqrt(jj**2-x1**2-z1**2)
                        zz = np.sqrt(jj**2-y1**2-x1**2)
                    print("x:", xx, "y:", yy,"z:", zz)
                kk +=1
```

And I am running it-
`create_points_around_atom(n=2,structure[1].coords)`
where, `structure[1].coords` is a numpy array of three coordinates.

Comment: what is the error you get ? be more specific :!

Comment: What's your *specific* question?

Comment: Dear @KlausD. it's printing all the coordinates instead of only which are inside or at the surface of the sphere. As I said in the main text that I want to get a numpy array of the coordinates of the points which are only either inside or at the surface of the sphere. For example, if out of 10 points (n=10) only 3 satisfy that criteria the program should give a 3*3 matrix of coordinates of those 3 points. [[x1,y1,z1],[x2,y2,z2]...]

Comment: Dear @DOOM I have explained it a bit more above

Comment: the problem are the lines `u = np.random.uniform(0,1,size=(n,))` and `r = R * np.cbrt(u)`. `u <= 1` so `r <= R`, hence all points created, are inside the sphere of radius `R`.

Comment: If you've already managed to *generate* the coordinates, why are you having trouble with simply adding them to an array? Unless you've copied this snippet from elsewhere and you don't understand what it does?

Comment: @meowgoesthedog, no I did not copy it from anywhere. The problem is I am not able to screen the points which are either inside the sphere or on the surface of the sphere and then print the coordinates in numpy matrix format. The ` if j <= R:` condition seems working but the `for kk in range(len(point_on_inside_sphere)):` loop is printing all the point's coordinates meaning if out of 10 points presumably, it should print only those point's coordinates which are either inside or on the surface of the sphere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To sum up what has been discussed in the comments, and some other points:

- There is no need to filter the points because `u <= 1`, which means `np.cbrt(u) <= 1` and hence `r = R * np.cbrt(u) <= R`, i.e. all points will already be inside or on the surface of the sphere.
- Calling `np.random.uniform` with `size=(n,)` creates an array of `n` elements, so there's no need to do this `n` times in a loop.
- You are filtering distances from the `atom_coordinate`, but the points you are generating are centered on `[0, 0, 0]`, because you are not adding this offset.
- Passing `R` as an argument seems more sensible than hard-coding it.
- There's no need to "pre-load" arguments in Python like one would sometimes do in C.
- Since `sin(theta)` is non-negative over the sphere, you can directly calculate it from the `costheta` array using the identity `cos²(x) + sin²(x) = 1`.

Sample implementation:

```
# pass radius as an argument
def create_points_around_atom(number, center, radius):

    # generate the random quantities
    phi         = np.random.uniform( 0, 2*np.pi, size=(number,))
    theta_cos   = np.random.uniform(-1,       1, size=(number,))
    u           = np.random.uniform( 0,       1, size=(number,))

    # calculate sin(theta) from cos(theta)
    theta_sin   = np.sqrt(1 - theta_cos**2)
    r           = radius * np.cbrt(u)

    # use list comprehension to generate the coordinate array without a loop
    # don't forget to offset by the atom's position (center)
    return np.array([
        np.array([
            center[0] + r[i] * theta_sin[i] * np.cos(phi[i]),
            center[1] + r[i] * theta_sin[i] * np.sin(phi[i]),
            center[2] + r[i] * theta_cos[i]
        ]) for i in range(number)
    ])
```